# Serialize XML node as document with correct namespaces

Tags: ruby, xml, namespaces, nokogiri

How can I serialize a XML node taken from a document into a standalone 
document? Using `node.to_xml` is not enough, because `to_xml` does not 
output all the needed namespaces, only those explicitly declared inside 
that node.

For example, I have this XML document in `doc`

```
 <wrapper xmlns="ns" xmlns:extra="extra">
     <record xml:id="r1">
         <field>aaa</field>
         <field extra:type="second">bbb</field>
     </record>
 </wrapper>
```

and I want to I isolate the node `#r1`.

```
 record = doc.at("//*[@xml:id='r1']")
```

Now, `record.to_xml` returns (reformatted)

```
 <record xml:id="r1">
     <field>aaa</field>
     <field extra:type="second">bbb</field>
 </record>
```

This result may be OK in some contexts, but it is not good for my 
purposes: the default namespace and the `extra` namespace have not been 
copied. What I want is a document in which all the needed namespaces 
have been copied, like the following:

```
 <record xml:id="r1" xmlns="ns" xmlns:extra="extra">
     <field>aaa</field>
     <field extra:type="second">bbb</field>
 </record>
```

How can I do this with Nokogiri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, emerged from [Nokogiri bug report #1200](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1200), is to `clone` the node before using it.

Using

```
record.clone.to_xml
```

instead of

```
record.to_xml
```

generates the correct XML document.